# I cannot insert data from asp.net into SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to insert data from ASP.net webforms into SQL Server but I get an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I don't understand this error, please help me find out what is what is this error.

```
Protected Sub Myinsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Myinsert.Click
    Dim dt As New Date
    dt = DateAndTime.Now.ToString
    p = "Image/" + ImgPath.FileName.ToString
    Try
        cn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyWebSite( img, type, title, short_para, full_para, datepost) VALUES('" & p & "','" & txtType.Text & "','" & txtTitle.Text & "','" & ParaTT.Text & "','" & Para.Text & "','" & dt & "')"

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You should use parametrized query and you can specify the types.

Comment: That's usually a mismatch between the date format you're using and the date format the server expects. E.g. you might be sending 'dd/mm/yyyy', where the server interprets it as 'mm/dd/yyyy', resulting in invalid dates. As @Zaki mentioned, using a parameterized query is a much better way to handle this.

Comment: The message is pretty obvious - the data passed was wrong, definitely because you created the SQL statement using string concatenation instead of using a parameterized query.

Comment: Do you know Little Bobby Tables?. Please, google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are open for sql injection if you use string concatenation to build your sql query. Instead always use sql-parameters. That also fixes other issue(f.e. date conversion).

Also, don't declare `Dim dt As New Date` and initialize it with a string. I strongly recommend to set `Option Strict` to `On`. That won't fix anything and also causes many compiler errors. But by fixing them you'll learn a lot about the .NET type system and you'll learn to write safer code which doesn't rely on implicit conversions (or is vulnerable to undesired conversions).

```
Protected Sub Myinsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Myinsert.Click
    Try
        Using cn = New SqlConnection("Connection String")
            Dim insertSQL = "INSERT INTO MyWebSite(img, type, title, short_para, full_para, datepost) VALUES(@img, @type, @title, @short_para, @full_para, @datepost)"
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand(insertSQL, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@img", SqlDbType.VarChar))
                cmd.Parameters(cmd.Parameters.Count - 1).Value = "Image/" + ImgPath.FileName.ToString()
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar))
                cmd.Parameters(cmd.Parameters.Count - 1).Value = "your type"
                ' ....... other parameters .....
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@datepost", SqlDbType.DateTime))
                cmd.Parameters(cmd.Parameters.Count - 1).Value = Date.Now

                cn.Open()
                Dim inserted As Int32 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using ' no need to close the connection due to the using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Note that i've used the `Using` statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed and the connection gets closed even on error.